# How to send the sqliteDatabase data via email, displaying it in the body of email?

Tags: email, android-sqlite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP1aS.png)

I have created a sqlite Database. Now I need to send it via email. I have been able. My code for getting the data from sqlite database is:-

```
    public ArrayList<ChickenLogs> getData() {

    ArrayList<ChickenLogs> log = new ArrayList<ChickenLogs>();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + DataBaseHelper.FOGHORN_TABLE;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    Log.i("cursor", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        ChickenLogs chickenLogs = new ChickenLogs();
        chickenLogs.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
        chickenLogs.setCatId(cursor.getInt(1));
        chickenLogs.setChickenId(cursor.getInt(2));
        chickenLogs.setDatetime(cursor.getString(3));
        chickenLogs.setWeight(cursor.getFloat(4));
        chickenLogs.setEggs(cursor.getInt(5));
        chickenLogs.setGrain(cursor.getFloat(6));
        chickenLogs.setWater(cursor.getFloat(7));
        log.add(chickenLogs);
    }
    return log;
}
```

and for sending the email, I am using asyncTask from mainActivity, just the problem is that how to display the contents of the database in the
body of the email. I would be really thankful, if anybody can help me out with this.

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ChickenLogs>> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public BackgroundTask(MainActivity activity) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Doing something, please wait.");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ChickenLogs> result) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                String[] to = {"er.aamanarora@gmail.com"};
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
                intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "mSubject.getText().toString()");
                if(result !=null) {
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, result);
                }
                final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
                ResolveInfo best = null;
                for(final ResolveInfo info : matches)
                    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail"))
                        best = info;
                if (best != null)
                    intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ChickenLogs> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                detailList= chickLogDAO.getData();
                Log.i("retData", String.valueOf(detailList));
                // return from detailList is of form [com.example.chickenlogs.utils.chickenlogs@24e59dd3]

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return detailList;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.